# How to delete multiple partitions in HIVE table

Tags: hive

I would like to delete multiple partitions in Hive table. I am able to delete specific partition using ALTER statement as follow :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (partition_col= val)
```

But it is not working with operators like `>` or `<`.

The error thrown is :

```
mismatched input '<' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 81)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. The command should work. alter table table_name drop partition (partition_col<val); . I used this and it worked fine.

Comment: mismatched input '<' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 81)